# using jquery steps ,how can we load last step directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I am new to jquery steps,I have requirement to load last step directly once form is loaded.
Can anybody suggest how can I achive this?

Comment: Please add HTML and JS code that you have written

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, instead of putting this in jquery.steps.js (which could cause your changes to be overridden when you upgrade), just put the following on the page you want to use steps in. You set the `startIndex` behavior. Below I left some of the other settings so you could see how the Behaviors [at jquery steps](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings#events) can be applied.

```
$("#steps").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        enableAllSteps: true,
        transitionEffect: "slide",
        stepsOrientation: "vertical",
        startIndex: 1, // Right here, you can set the index of the item you want to change.
    });
```

Comment: this gives me  "out of range" error  in  console  , even though  I'm having 5 steps and I  want to  load 4th step based  on condition ,  but it is not working . kindly help

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to go directly to last step, change one property in jquery.steps.js file

`startIndex: 0`,

Add your last steps number in place of '0'.